# Play MIDI from Raspi using external controller

Tags: audio, midi

I want to output MIDI fonts from the Raspberry Pi, hopefully able to control it with external sensors.

I have timidity installed but get no sound playing the file python_games/tetrisc.mid . Is there another component to outputting sound?

Answer (score 1):

By "MIDI fonts" you mean soundfonts, right? If so, you could use [mingus](https://code.google.com/p/mingus/) with fluidsynth installed. to use midi-input, try using [pygame.midi](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html)
I hope I could help you!

Comment: I hope so too! I'll try Mingus ASAP