# Which hardware to connect a MIDI keyboard to the RPi?

Tags: raspbian, midi

As I can see from questions like

- [MIDI keyboard latency with fluidsynth](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14987/midi-keyboard-latency-with-fluidsynth)
- [Play MIDI from Raspi using external controller](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/play-midi-from-raspi-using-external-controller?rq=1)

and external blog posts like

- [Jacques Pi Synthesizer](http://jacquespi.blogspot.de/2013/07/synthesizer.html)

I see that it is possible to play MIDI. Unfortunately, none of the question specifies the hardware needed to achieve this. Do I need a shield or is it a USB to MIDI adapter? Can I just use any or should I pick one for which drivers are available?

My OS would be Raspbian. I have Model 2B. Low latency would be preferred if there are multiple options.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a USB-MIDI adapter. They should work natively on Raspbian.

**Update:** I found [this handy guide](http://andrewdotni.ch/blog/2015/02/28/midi-synth-with-raspberry-p/).

Answer (score 3):

Any standard USB MIDI class device will work and is supported by the linux kernel. So, most any music keyboard with a USB connection, or a USB-to-MIDI dongle. IIRC some Yamaha keyboards in the Portable Grand line may not support USB MIDI class and need a custom driver; I'm not sure if linux supports these.