# raspi MIDI in audio out

Tags: audio, input-device, midi

I have a MIDI controller keyboard, that I want to take with me to a vacation. For some reason I cannot bring a tablet/laptop with me. I still have a Raspberry Pi 2B lying around so I thought it might be possible to use the USB MIDI controller as input, apply a piano sound and directly output it through the aux port. Is this possible and if it is, how can it be done?

Comment: See [Which hardware to connect a MIDI keyboard to the RPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51465/which-hardware-to-connect-a-midi-keyboard-to-the-rpi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which hardware to connect a MIDI keyboard to the RPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51465/which-hardware-to-connect-a-midi-keyboard-to-the-rpi)